# Improve INSERT-Access-VBA in accdb file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following code in my Access VBA program but it is giving me an error when I run the code.
I created table with Table1 of name and I wanted to insert a new record into the table.
But the code had a error.
The Error is like this.

*Object variable or With block Variable not set*

```
Sub Insert()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim StrSQL As String
    StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('1', 'Fuji')"
    db.Execute (StrSQL)
    db.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You've not set `db` to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to take advantage of `CurrentDb`:

```vb
Sub Insert()

    Dim StrSQL As String

    StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('1', 'Fuji')"
    CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL

End Sub
```

And if the first field is *numeric*, no quotes:

```vb
    StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, 'Fuji')"
```